# How to hide code from mochawesome report?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, mochawesome

I use the selenium web driver together with mochawesome. I would like to disable the display of code in the report, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I added the `--no-code` to the script as described in the documentation, but the code is still displayed.

`"scripts": { "test": "mocha --timeout 0 --reporter mochawesome --no-code --reporter-options reportFilename=report" }`

Also i tried `--code=false`, but it didn't help.

Comment: I used with code=false, and it is working fine now.